# MapActivity Gesture Problem

Tags: android, android-maps

I use a MapActivity and have the following problem:

When I zoomin or zoomout with a multitouch-gesture, sometimes the Map freezes and a blank display is shown. Has anybody seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have posted some code here which works for me.
[Random MapView Force Close : NullPointerException com.google.googlenav.map.Tile.getTile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290833/random-mapview-force-close-nullpointerexception-com-google-googlenav-map-tile-g/5290963#5290963)

I think this happens when you zoom in too much and the MapView does not find the tiles.