# Random MapView Force Close : NullPointerException com.google.googlenav.map.Tile.getTile

Tags: android, android-mapview

I really need some help. I have a report of a force close with this stack trace, and I cant find any information on how to prevent, nor can I replicate this type of error. I was hoping someone would have some insight on why this is happening.

```
com.google.googlenav.map.Tile.getTile(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.Tile.read(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile.read(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.FlashRecord.loadTileFromDataEntry(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.FlashRecord.loadTile(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.MapFlashService.loadFlashRecordTile(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.MapFlashService.getMapTile(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.MapService.getTile(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
android.view.View.draw(View.java:6739)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)
android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)
android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not my own but this is what fixed crashes on my MapView

```
public class TrackMapView extends MapView {
    public TrackMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs); 
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        try {
            if(this.getZoomLevel() >= 21) {
                this.getController().setZoom(20);
            }
            super.draw(canvas);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {           
            getController().setCenter(this.getMapCenter());
            getController().setZoom(this.getZoomLevel() - 2);
            Log.d("TrackMapView", "Internal error in MapView:" + Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so you surrounded super.draw() in a try/catch... I'll have to try this and see how it behaves. Thank you for your fast response.